# ffmpeg as subprocess takes too long

Tags: python, asynchronous, ffmpeg, subprocess, python-3.6

One part of my program requires FFMPEG to transcode files using GPU.

When I execute the FFMPEG command alone in terminal, without Python, it takes aproximetly 0.7 second. Running 50 simultaneous commands doesn't affect the results. The time is always around 0.7 sec (thanks to a powerful GPU that can handle that amount of requests).

Putting this command to subprocess increases the time to 1.7 second and raises up to 20 seconds when I run multiple instance even though this command should work asynchronously.

```py
def run_ffmpeg(filename, gop, representation, output_filename=None):
    process_result = subprocess.run(
        args=[
            'sudo', FFMPEG_PATH,
            '-vsync', '0',
            '-hwaccel', 'cuvid', # transport decoded file through GPU without touching CPU
            '-hwaccel_device', '0',
            '-c:v', 'h264_cuvid', # Decoding using GPU
            '-i', filename,
            # ...
            '-c:v', 'hevc_nvenc', # Encoding using GPU
            # ...more filters...
            output_filename
        ]
    )
    log_process_result(process_result)
    return output_filename
```

The sequence is way more complex:

```py
def transcode_file(media_id, target_repr, target_nr):
    # ... variables definitions
    run_ffmpeg(target_segment_path, gop='120', representation=target_repr, output_filename=result)

def prepare_file(media_id, representation_id, file_name):
    # ... variables definitions
        path = transcode_file(media_id, target_repr, target_nr)

async def download_media_handler(request):
    # ... variables definitions
    file_info = await loop.run_in_executor(
        executor, prepare_file, media_dir_name, representation_id, file_name)
```

Neither GPU or CPU is fully used so this is not the case.

Do you know why? Does `subprocess` really takes so much time to run?

How can I rewrite this to minimize the time? Are there any quicker alternatives?

Comment: Can you share the part of your code which calls this function? See: [mcve].

Comment: I added full sequence to show the async part, maybe it'll help